# Getting a ClassNotFoundException on running test with Gradle and jUnit

Tags: java, gradle, junit5

I'm new with Gradle and I'm trying to run a simple build scenario. I've added two classes: src/main/java/ExampleApp and src/test/java/ExampleTest into the project directory tree:

```
│
└───src
    ├───main
    │   └───java
    │           ExampleApp.java
    │
    └───test
        └───java
                ExampleTest.java
```

My build.gradle.kts is:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("jvm-test-suite")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "ExampleApp"
    }
}

testing {
    suites { 
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) { 
            useJUnitJupiter() 
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0")
}
```

Running

```
./gradlew clean test
```

the test task is failing. In the test-report I've found this:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not execute test class 'ExampleTest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:54)
    at java.base@21.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base@21.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleTest
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.loadClass(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.access$100(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.execute(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ExampleTest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.loadClass(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:168)
    ... 21 more
```

The class tree I've found is:

```
│
├───build
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───java
│   │       ├───main
│   │       │       ExampleApp.class
│   │       │
│   │       └───test
│   │               ExampleTest.class
```

With Maven everithing is working as expected. The same classes, the same structure. With jUnit4 the results are the same.
What did I miss with Gradle?

P.S. Windows 11, JDK 21, Gradle 8.6

P.P.S. I've cloned [a sample jUnit5](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples.git) and tried to test. I've got identical type of error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.project.CalculatorTests
```

Looks like something is wrong with the classpath at testing.

**Update:** have run on macOS and everything is working as expected!

Comment: Quite mysterious: your setup works fine on my machine (though it's not Windows and with slightly different versions of everything). I'd be debugging the code in your shoes. Bit concerning and surprising a very basic setup can go awry

Comment: @SimonJacobs On MacOS everything is building without problems, test is passed. 
This issue is driving me nuts :)